# Why does Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online require access to https://www.crmdyntint.com?

Tags: security, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-dynamics-crm

The list of ["Internet accessible URLs required for connectivity to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2655102/internet-accessible-urls-required-for-connectivity-to-microsoft-dynami) is comprised almost entirely of Microsoft owned domains.

However, I cannot understand why access to the URL https://www.crmdyntint.com is required. Visiting this URL with a web browser just displays a generic domain parking page with ads, which makes me worry about the security of the domain. According to a Whois [lookup](https://www.whois.com/whois/crmdyntint.com) the domain is owned by a Hong Kong based firm named [China Capital](http://www.chinacapital.com/the-firm/).

Does anyone know why access to https://www.crmdyntint.com is required by Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the url. Actually it should be https://www.crmdynint.com and not https://www.crmdyntint.com (see the extra "t")

I see [Microsoft updated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2655102/internet-accessible-urls-required-for-connectivity-to-microsoft-dynami) the article recently. Probably they fixed it.

> Last Updated: 16/05/2018

This url is just needed for "Learning Path" & it is a traffic monitoring site.

Answer (score 1):

The list is probably outdated. That domain was just registered two weeks ago.

```
Creation Date: 2018-02-19T07:00:00.000Z
```

So it's likely a previously expired domain that was used for something else.

The KB article was last updated almost a year ago.

> Last Updated: 28/06/2017

Personally I would not bother to whitelist this URL.